# click on link with curl php

Tags: php, curl

i want to know how to click on link with curl in php. i pass login page but when i want to create new curl_exec to click a tag, i cant get any thing.
the a tag make xhr request to get some data , i pass all form data , but still have problem.
note:my website that i want get content with curl was asp.

```
$this->_ch = curl_init(); 
        $this->config(); // normal config for curl
        if (!empty($this->_fields)) {
            $fields = http_build_query($this->_fields, '', '&');
            curl_setopt($this->_ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
        } else {
            curl_setopt($this->_ch, CURLOPT_POST, false);
        }
        if($testparam !="")
        {           
            curl_setopt($this->_ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $testparam);
        }
        $result = curl_exec($this->_ch);
        $this->_curlInfo = curl_getinfo($this->_ch);
        $this->_lastResult = $result;
        $this->_fields = array();
        if (!$this->curlCheckError()) {
            $result = null;
        }
        return $result;


//send param
  $params['__EVENTTARGET']='ctl00$MainContent$RadGrid1';
  $newParam.='__VIEWSTATE='.$test['__VIEWSTATE'];
```

.
.
.
and send more param.

but still can't simulate click that a tag in this url .
any idea or sample how to click a tag with curl that run script from ajax..?
i need return value of link click with curl.
tnx a lot.

Comment: You cannot *simulate* the click of an A tag in your cURL request, sorry. Unfortunately `cURL` will not wait for anything and will return, simply put, the plain text contents of that page. Unfortunately, this is the way that it is. Your solution would be to use a server-side browser for this task. `Node` has some packages if you're familiar with the language.

Comment: thanks for your reply, it mean i cant make curl call to other website , then click the a tag for filling some part of page and get content of it?(clicking on a tag with sending post data that xhr send ) ?

Comment: You won't be able to do that with cURL alone, unfortunately.